# Java Regex for String extraction

Tags: java, regex, string

I want to extract "Little League World Series" from the input below:

```
<li><span class="Spicy new"><a href="http://www.google.com/trends/hottrends#a=20120825-Little%2BLeague%2BWorld%2BSeries">Little League World Series</a></span></li>
```

I can either replace the strings before and after it with "", or I can extract the string.
I am not able to get the right regex to do this. I am using `line.replace(" <li><span class=\"[\\w]+\"", "");` to replace the part before "Little League World Series", but it does not match correctly.

Would appreciate any help.

Comment: Any reason you're using RegEx and not a DOM or XML parser?

Comment: because I just want the terms ( one of the values) its easier to use regex string parsing, rather than including an extra library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```
<li><span class="[^"]+"><a href="[^"]+">[^>]+</a></span></li>
```

to get the whole line. Then replace

```
<li><span class="[^"]+"><a href="[^"]+">
```

with "" and replace

```
</a></span></li>
```

with ""

Try the below link.it also shows the java string required. 
http://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/java/index.html

For use of the java function check this link:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#replaceFirst(java.lang.String)

Comment: cant use full string match, I want to match multiple strings in this format returned from http://www.google.com/trends/hottrends/atom/hourly?country=usa

Comment: actually I was able to use line = line.replace(line.substring(line.indexOf("</a>")), "");
                            line = line.replace(line.substring(0,line.lastIndexOf(">"))+ 1, "");

Comment: Its a hack, not pretty but it serves the purpose for me.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this to remove the stuff in front of the line:

```
line.replaceFirst("<li><span class=\"[^\"]+\"><a href=\"[^\"]+\">", "");
```

Try it [on regexr](http://regexr.com?320ed)

**Edit:** `String.replace` does not accept regexes, `String.replaceFirst` does.

Comment: Damn, `String.replace` doesn't accept regexes, you need to use `String.replaceFirst`. Well, that's what I get for only trying it on regexr, I suppose :)

Answer (score 1):

If this is not a well formed trusted html source, use an html parser like JSOUP. Regex cannot protect you against many malformed html issues.

Answer (score 0):

This one seems to pass:

```
    @Test
    public void patternTest() {
        final String text = "<li><span class=\"Spicy new\"><a href=\"http://www.google.com/trends/hottrends#a=20120825-Little%2BLeague%2BWorld%2BSeries\">Little League World Series</a></span></li>";
        final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^.*>([^<>]+)<.*$");
        final Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(text);
        assertTrue(matcher.matches());
        assertEquals("Little League World Series", matcher.group(1));
    }
```

It extracts last non-empty text that goes between ">" and "<"